# Form wont submit using AJAX when logged out

Tags: commerce, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit the Add To Cart form using AJAX, I have altered the form like so:

```
function ajaxcart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if(strstr($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_')) {

    // Process the submit button which uses ajax
    $form['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
       'callback' => 'ajaxcart_submit_callback',
    );

    // dpm($form);

    }

}
```

Call Back Function

```
function ajaxcart_submit_callback($form, $form_state) {
  global $user;

  $form = drupal_rebuild_form($form['#form_id'], $form_state, $form);

  $commands = array();

  $commands[] = array('command' => 'ajaxcart_update') ;
  $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#block-system-main', theme('status_messages'));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.' . drupal_html_class($form['#form_id']), drupal_render($form));
  $commands[] = array(
    'command' => 'ajaxCartFireTrigger',
    'data'    => $form['#form_id'] 
  );

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

}
```

I have done a dump of the form and the ajax attribute has been added to the submit button. Problem is it will not work on the frontend while logged out. If I am logged in it works just fine and shows the throbber etc. beside the button.

The strange thing is, that it will work occasionally after the product has been added to the cart via the normal page refresh. To me its like it is missing the AJAX behaviors or something. Also while logged in, the button has the class 'ajax-processed' added, whereas it doesn't if not.

I have compared both and I cannot see what is wrong. Anyone got any suggestions to the problem?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Are you using Drupal Commerce? Not sure if you have seen this but the is a module for it https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_cart

Comment: Yeah I know about that module, but for me it limited, for example it uses a view which I don't want to do.

Comment: The fact that 'ajax-processed'class is not on the button when not logged in is a clue to your problem. Are there any js error on the page?